# Sum of multiple joined tables through a joined table

Tags: mysql

I have the query below which is getting the `subscriptions` per `projects` per `course` where the projects first date is after a specific date. However I would like to get the total amount of `subscriptions` for each course.

```
SELECT
    `courses`.`name`,
    (
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM `participant_subscriptions`
            WHERE `participant_subscriptions`.`project_id` = `projects`.`id` AND `projects`.`course_id` = `courses`.`id`
        ) + (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM `participant_subscription_project`
            WHERE `participant_subscription_project`.`project_id` = `projects`.`id` AND `projects`.`course_id` = `courses`.`id`
        )
    ) AS `subscriptions`
FROM `courses`
JOIN `projects` ON `courses`.`id` = `projects`.`course_id`
WHERE (SELECT MIN(`date`) FROM `project_dates` WHERE `projects`.`id` = `project_dates`.`project_id`) >= '2020-01-01'
```

This is the result from the query above:

```
| name     | subscriptions |
| Basics   | 6             |
| Basics   | 6             |
| Advanced | 2             |
| Advanced | 4             |
| Medium   | 2             |
```

What I would like to get is the following:

```
| name     | subscriptions |
| Basics   | 12            |
| Advanced | 6             |
| Medium   | 2             |
```

`courses` table:

- id
- name

`projects` table:

- id
- name
- course_id

`project_dates` table

- id
- date
- project_id

`participant_subscriptions` table

- id
- participant_id
- project_id

`participant_subscription_project` table

- id
- participant_id
- project_id

Comment: can you show the raw table data, I believe it could be re-written more easily

Comment: @HelloWorld I cant give raw table data. However I can add a bit more info about the tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to adjust the answer of @KonstantinL. You need to give the sub-query a `alias` as well. I ended up with the following:

```
SELECT `data`.`name`, SUM(`data`.`subscriptions`) AS `subscriptions`
        FROM (SELECT `c`.`name`,
                     (
                     (SELECT COUNT(*)
                              FROM `participant_subscriptions` `ps`
                              WHERE `ps`.`project_id` = `p`.`id`
            AND `p`.`course_id` = `c`.`id`) +
            (SELECT COUNT(*)
                              FROM `participant_subscription_project` `psp`
                              WHERE `psp`.`project_id` = `p`.`id`
            AND `p`.`course_id` = `c`.`id`)
                         ) AS `subscriptions`,
              FROM `courses` `c`
                       JOIN `projects` `p`
                            ON `c`.`id` = `p`.`course_id`
             WHERE (
                 SELECT MIN(`date`)
                 FROM `project_dates`
                 WHERE `projects`.`id` = `project_dates`.`project_id`
              ) >= '2020-01-01')
         )AS `data`
        GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Hm... Why can't you use subquery with `group by`?

```
select name, sum(subscriptions) from
(SELECT `courses`.`name`,
       (
               (SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM `participant_subscriptions`
                WHERE `participant_subscriptions`.`project_id` = `projects`.`id`
                  AND `projects`.`course_id` = `courses`.`id`) +
               (SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM `participant_subscription_project`
                WHERE `participant_subscription_project`.`project_id` = `projects`.`id`
                  AND `projects`.`course_id` = `courses`.`id`)
           ) AS `subscriptions`
FROM `courses`
    JOIN `projects`
        ON `courses`.`id` = `projects`.`course_id`
WHERE (
          SELECT MIN(`date`)
          FROM `project_dates`
          WHERE `projects`.`id` = `project_dates`.`project_id`
      ) >= '2020-01-01')
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: That gives the exact same result without giving the total amount of subscriptions per course

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
SELECT
    c.name,
    (
        ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM participant_subscriptions ps WHERE ps.project_id = p.id AND p.course_id = c.id ) + 
        ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM participant_subscription_project psp WHERE psp.project_id = p.id AND p.course_id = c.id)
    ) AS subscriptions
FROM courses c
JOIN projects p ON c.id = p.course_id
WHERE (SELECT MIN(date) FROM project_dates WHERE p.id = project_dates.project_id) >= '2020-01-01'
GROUP BY `courses`.`id` -- <--- edited
```

**or**

```
SELECT 
    c.name,
    COUNT(ps.id) participant_subscriptions_count,
    COUNT(psp.id) participant_subscription_project_count,
FROM projects p
    LEFT JOIN participant_subscriptions ps ON ps.project_id = p.id
    LEFT JOIN participant_subscription_project psp ON psp.project_id = p.id
    LEFT JOIN courses c ON c.id = p.course_id
-- WHERE (SELECT MIN(date) FROM project_dates WHERE p.id = project_dates.project_id) >= '2020-01-01' -- remove where consition for debugging
GROUP BY c.id
```

above SQL is a different approach. you have to add `participant_subscriptions_count` and `participant_subscription_project_count` with any programming language

Comment: It still doesn't give the the SUM of all subscriptions per course

Comment: since I have to use `sql-mode=only_full_group_by` I can't group by on a single value

Comment: It feels wrong to do: "add `participant_subscriptions_count` and `participant_subscription_project_count` with any programming language"

Comment: `COUNT(ps.id) + COUNT(psp.id) AS subscriptions`  you can do this

Comment: is the value is appearing as you expected??

Comment: No it still isn't